# Is it better to call table once in a CTE, then call the CTE multiple times or call the 1 table multiple times in different CTEs

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sample Query 1

```
WITH sample_1 AS (
SELECT * FROM table_1
),
transform_1 AS (
SELECT * FROM sample_1 JOIN table_2 on .. 
),
transform_2 AS (
SELECT * FROM sample_1 JOIN table_3 on .. 
)
SELECT * FROM transform_1 JOIN transform_2
```

Sample Query 2

```
WITH 
transform_1 AS (
SELECT * FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 on .. 
),
transform_2 AS (
SELECT * FROM table_1 JOIN table_3 on .. 
)
SELECT * FROM transform_1 JOIN transform_2
```

Im trying to make my code more efficient and easy to read

Comment: "my code more efficient and easy to read" <-- These tend to be _mutually exclusive_ goals.

Comment: Have you compared their query execution plans? If not, **why not**?

Comment: Query time is similar

Comment: I didn't ask you to compare execution _times_, I asked you to [compare the execution _plans_](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html).

Comment: I never considered look at this, thank you will study this

Answer (score 0):

Some general guidelines I would follow: Use a CTE if at least one of the following is true:

- it encapsulates some meaningful application logic, such as
  predicates, joins and aggregations, especially if this logic
  is used more than once in the query (for example: Sales from last year),
- it contains SQL operations with the potential to be shared between
  multiple parts of the query, such as doing a
  scan, join or aggregation just once for multiple consumers.

Without any predicates, it is unlikely the above CTEs will get any benefit, but let's assume (using sample query 1) transform_1 has a predicate

```
WHERE sample_1.a in (10, 20)
```

and transform_2 has a predicate

```
WHERE sample_1.a in (20, 30)
```

That would allow us to make a CTE for sample_1 with a predicate

```
WHERE table_1.a in (10, 20, 30)
```

That could result in a better performing plan. So, this would be an example of my second bullet above. I've seen this kind of optimization with the ORCA optimizer in Greenplum (based on Postgres), but am not sure whether the Postgres planner will also choose the same optimization.